# Error in python selenium 3 Edge web driver

Tags: python, selenium, microsoft-edge

I am a complete beginner to selenium and I wrote my first program just to connect to Google.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
path = "C:\\Users\\Home\\Documents\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\Code\\msedgedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Edge(path)

driver.get("https://google.com")

print(driver.title)"
```

My web driver version is `88.0.705.50 (Official build) (64-bit)`

I use selenium 3 and I am getting this error while running the code. Also it is opening `"data:,"` for a few seconds then opening Google. Lastly the browser doesn't stay open.

Comment: Well, it doesn't stay open bcs you didn't give him any more commands so it shuts down. To keep it open you can use `time.sleep()`

Answer (score 1):

- Declare path on a separate line from the import statement
- Use raw string in path or double escapes

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = r"C:\Users\Home\Documents\Python37-32\Scripts\Code\msedgedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Edge(path)
driver.get("https://google.com")
print(driver.title)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Will definitely try it out

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? It's the default behavior that the browser opens with `data:,`, then it will direct to the website you want. The browser doesn't stay opened may because the error breaks it.

You can refer to the following steps to automate Edge in python selenium:

- Make sure the WebDriver version is the same as the Edge version.
- Install the MS Edge Selenium tools using command below:

  ```
  pip install msedge-selenium-tools selenium==3.141
  ```
- Sample code:

  ```
  from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions
  options = EdgeOptions()
  options.use_chromium = True
  driver = Edge(executable_path = r"C:\Users\Home\Documents\Python37-32\Scripts\Code\msedgedriver.exe", options = options)
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  print(driver.title)
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much I'm gonna try it out and get back to you guys.

Comment: Yeah i didnt quite test the code which you have posted because i shifted to another device just recently and installed the chrome driver instead of edge driver. And yes i will refer it